# How to get previous item in each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a SQL query that loads information into a hash. I want to iterate through that information and output it into the view.

If the `user_id` is the same as the previous object's `user_id`, I don't want to display that `user_id`, just the name and everything else. It seems like the logic should be simple, but being a novice at Ruby and Rails, I'm not sure what is really available to do this.

I was trying something like this, but `prev_id` was never getting updated after the first iteration:

```
<% @session.each_with_index do |s, x| %>
    <% if x == 0 then prev_id = 'nil' end %>
    <% curr_id = s['id'] %>


    <% if curr_id != prev_id %>
        <%= s['id'] %>
    <% end %>

    <%= s['name'] %>
    <%= s['count'] %><br>
    <% prev_id = curr_id %>
<% end %>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Matt, I suggest that in future you hold off awhile before making a selection (perhaps at least a couple of hours). A quick selection may discourage other answers and imo is inconsiderate to those still working on their answers. There's no rush.

Comment: Your logic should not be in your view, it should be in your controller. Assign the results to a variable and access the variable in the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare your `prev_id` outside of the loop for it to persist between iterations:

```
<% prev_id = nil %>
<% @session.each_with_index do |s, x| %>
    <% if x == 0 then prev_id = 'nil' end %>
    <% curr_id = s['id'] %>


    <% if curr_id != prev_id %>
        <%= s['id'] %>
    <% end %>

    <%= s['name'] %>
    <%= s['count'] %><br>
    <% prev_id = curr_id %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Of course it would be something that simple. Thank you very much. 

i'll accept answer when I can.

Comment: @Matt-Lepley Cheers! [This might help](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Variable_Scope) for understanding variable scope

Answer (score 3):

You should use `chunk`.

```
<% @session.chunk{|s| s["id"]}.each do |curr_id, a| %>
  <%= curr_id %>
  <% a.each do |s| %>    
    <%= s["name"] %>
    <%= s["count"] %><br>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hey @sawa, I appreciate the help, but I also need the name to only appear one time just like the id. I'm not sure if that is possible to do with chunk.

Comment: Matt, just change `<%= s["name'] %>` to `<%= a.first["name"] %>` and move it to precede `<% a.each do |s| %>`.  If you wanted different formatting for the first record of the chunk, process the first record entirely out of the loop and then `a[1..-1].each do |s| %...`.   [Enumerable#chunk](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) is the Ruby way for your problem.

Comment: Wow, `chunk` is really interesting method. 12 years into Ruby and never heard of it. It's like `group_by` but only groups consecutively similar items. Fascinating.